# How can i detect symbols using regular expression in perl?

Tags: perl

Please how can i use regular expression to check if word starts or ends with a symbol character, also how to can i process the text within the symbol.

Example:

- `(text) or te-xt, or tex't. or text?`

  change it to
- `(<t>text</t>) or <t>te-xt</t>, or <t>tex't</t>. or <t>text</t>?`

help me out?

Thanks

Comment: What if a word starts or ends with a space? Is that considered a "symbol"?

Comment: What about words with apostrophes, like `don't`?

Comment: words with apostrophes & dash are text as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using DVK's approach here, but with a slight modification. The difference is that her/his code would also put the tags around all words that don't contain/are next to a symbol, which (according to the example given in the question) is not desired.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub modify {
   my $input     = shift;
   my $text_char = 'a-zA-Z0-9\-\''; # characters that are considered text

   # if there is no symbol, don't change anything
   if ($input =~ /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/) {
      return $input;
   }
   else {
      $input =~ s/([$text_char]+)/<t>$1<\/t>/g;
      return $input;
   }
}

my $initial_string  = "(text) or te-xt, or tex't. or text?";
my $expected_string = "(<t>text</t>) or <t>te-xt</t>, or <t>tex't</t>. or <t>text</t>?";

# version BEFORE edit 1:
#my @aux;

# take the initial string apart and process it one word at a time
#my @string_list = split/\s+/, $initial_string;
#
#foreach my $string (@string_list) {
#   $string = modify($string);
#   push @aux, $string;
#}
#
# put the string together again
#my $final_string = join(' ', @aux);

# ************ EDIT 1 version ************
my $final_string = join ' ', map { modify($_) } split/\s+/, $initial_string;    

if ($final_string eq $expected_string) {
   print "it worked\n";
}
```

This strikes me as a somewhat long-winded way of doing it, but it seemed quicker than drawing up a more sophisticated regex...

**EDIT 1:** I have incorporated the changes suggested by DVK (using map instead of foreach). Now the syntax highlighting is looking even worse than before; I hope it doesn't obscure anything...

Comment: It's almost a +1 but please convert the whole split/foreach/join into an idiomatic one liner using map instead of foreach to make it more succint :)

Comment: @DVK I did consider using map, but a) I reckoned aliocee was a beginner, so I thought seeing what's going on would be easier for her/him if I kept things apart a bit; b) it's late at night and this was easier & quicker for me ;)  But you are right, of course!

Comment: No need to use the block form of `map` if you've got a nice sub to work with.  Just say `map modify($_), split/\s+/, $initial_string;`

Comment: Thank alot guys u r my heros!

Answer (score 5):

I assume that "word" means alphanumeric characters from your example? If you have a list of **permitted** characters which constitute a valid word, then this is enough:

```
my $string = "x1 .text1; 'text2 \"text3;\"";
$string =~ s/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/<t>$1<\/t>/g; 
              # Add more to character class [a-zA-Z0-9] if needed
print "$string\n";
# OUTPUT: <t>x1</t> .<t>text1</t>; '<t>text2</t> "<t>text3</t>;"
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your example you seem to want to DELETE dashes and apostrophes, if you want to delete them globally (e.g. whether they are inside the word or not), before the first regex, you do

```
$string =~ s/['-]//g;
```

Comment: This also changes text like "text text" that doesnt end in a symbol.

Comment: justintime - I understand the OP to include spaces into "symbols" - I could be wrong.

Comment: what about words with DASH character? i consider whose as text.

Comment: @aliocee - Just add a DASH at the very end of the class: `[a-zA-Z0-9-]` (if it's in the middle, it's considered a special "range" character, but if it's at the end of the character class it's just plain dash character)

Comment: If you want to DELETE them as in your example, see update to the question

Comment: @DVK- How about real numbers? eg. 0.78 or 0.98

Comment: @aliocee - a period (.) in a character class has no special meaning so you can add it (unlike outside of character class).

Comment: @aliocee - you're welcome. If this was helpful, feel free to up-vote the answer (up-arrow next to it) and mark it as "accepted" (checkmark next to it)

Comment: @DVK If I am not mistaken your solution will also put the tags around words that don't contain/are next to any symbols, like the "or" in aliocee's example. Those should not be changed though (by the look of it).

Comment: @canavanin - I tried to clarify via a comment to the Q but didn't get an answer. I'm not quite sure what he is trying to achieve and doing "punctuation only" thing seems less likely than "wrap any word", though I could very well be wrong. While his example didn't contain any non-punctuation-surrounded words, it's not clear if that's meant as "don't wrap anything else".

Answer (score 2):

This takes standard input and processes it to and prints on Standard output.

```
    while (<>) {
       s {
           (  [a-zA-z]+  )     # word
           (?= [,.)?] )        # a symbol
         }
         {<t>$1</t>}gx ;
       print ;
    }
```

You might need to change the bit to match the concept of word. 
I have use the `x` modifeid to allow the regexx to be spaced over more than one line.

If the input is in a Perl variable, try

```
         $string =~ s{
           (  [a-zA-z]+  )     # word
           (?= [,.)?] )        # a symbol
         }
         {<t>$1</t>}gx ;
```